# SublimeVideo won't load in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, flash, video

Just a quick question, hope this can be resolved fast.

I implemented a video switcher (slides between two videos) on a customer's website using jQuery and SublimeVideo (http://baeckerei-glasenapp.de/unternehmen/#videos)

For some reason, SublimeVideo doesn't seem to want to load (in flash mode, duh). I mean, it tries to load the video, but I don't get an error.

Do I need some kind of polyfill, or is there maybe even something wrong with the video encoding? Or is it just my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    sublimevideo.ready(function() {
        $(".videoSelector li a").click(function(ev) {
            sublimevideo.stop();
            $(".videoSelector li a").removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var selectedVideo = $(this).attr('href');
            var index = $(".videolist li").index($(selectedVideo));
            if (index != -1) {
                var newLeft = '-' + parseInt($(selectedVideo).width() * index) + 'px';
                $(".videolist").animate({
                    left: newLeft
                }, 300);
            }
            ev.preventDefault();
        });
        $(".videoSelector li:first-child a").click();
    });
});
```